# VB.NET Shapes.AddPicture with aspect ratio

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a program written in vB.NET. I have a problem i am "exporting" an excel file with some data from database. One of the data has a link to file in it. I want to put this image (in the link) to the excel, It all works good until i have. for example image that is wide, or a tall one (landscape or portrait). I am using this code to poste the image to the excel file:

```
objWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(linktofile, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Left:=10, Top:=419, Height:=285, Width:=510)
```

so the proble is how to put the `AspectRatio := True` to the code...

Comment: you cant specify the aspect ratio if you're specifying sizes... Try set the height and width to -1 to maintain the size.

Comment: that is not the case. I have to make the image smaller (or equal) to height 285 points... my solution so far is convert the height of image to points and do a loop of division by 1,5 until the height of the image is not equal to or less than 285 point... the same aplies to its height (to not lose the quality of image)

Comment: then set the height to 285 points and the width as -1. that should work as you need :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you import the image with its original dimensions using "-1" for both the height and width, you can then select it, and set the height or width and maintain the aspect ratio.

For example:

```
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=Filename, linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=-1, Height:=-1).Select
    End With

    Set theShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)

    With theShape
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 'can be set to msoFalse if you don't need to lock aspect ratio
        '.Width = 50
        .Height = 50
    End With
```

I hope that this helps!